# What is Different between After And For in Triggers?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, triggers

What is For usage and diffrence between after and for???

**Update** Which One is Compatible with Standard Sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FOR | AFTER**

AFTER specifies that the DML trigger is fired only when all operations specified in the triggering SQL statement have executed successfully. All referential cascade actions and constraint checks also must succeed before this trigger fires.

AFTER is the default when FOR is the only keyword specified.

AFTER triggers cannot be defined on views.

**FOR and AFTER are the same, INSTEAD OF is different, see Books Online for details**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: Which one is compatible with Sql Standard?

Comment: @Lightwing - I don't think triggers are covered by the SQL Standards (certainly they don't seem to be based on publicly available drafts of 92 and 99)

Comment: @Damien: SQL:2003 ([draft](http://www.wiscorp.com/sql_2003_standard.zip)) seems to have made up for that deficiency. Seems like the standard keyword for this case is AFTER.